# How to authorize in a maven repository using drone.io

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, drone.io

So I got a self-hosted instance of [drone](https://drone.io) running on my server alongside a nexus3 repository.
Now I have a java project that should be built, tested and then deployed into the repository every push, which works fine until we get to the deployment part. I found the plugin on the official site for plugins, [Maven Auth](http://plugins.drone.io/robertstettner/drone-mvn-auth/) which is supposed to create a settings.xml based on the configuration, that works (made my pipeline output the contents of the file via cat and showed a valid settings.xml file).
The next step is configured to run

`mvn deploy -B -s settings.xml`

For some reason, maven doesn't use the username and password provided in the settings.xml (the server always returns an Unauthorized 401 error)

Entire .drone.yml:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default
type: docker

steps:
  - name: compile
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    commands:
      - mvn compile -B -U
    when:
      event:
        - push
  - name: test
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    commands:
      - mvn test -B
    when:
      event:
        - push
  - name: authenticate
    image: robertstettner/drone-mvn-auth
    settings:
      servers:
        - id: some-id (same in pom.xml distribution repos)
          username: username
          password:
            from_secret: repo_password
  - name: deploy_repo
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    commands:
      - mvn deploy -B -gs settings.xml
    when:
      event:
        - push
```

Some advice why this doesn't work would be dope! Thanks in advance!

Edit 2:
So I investigated further and installed [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/) on my server to analyze the traffic (Client -> Nginx SSL termination proxy -> mitmproxy -> running nexus).

To authorize apparently maven uses a header called "Authorization". And the content is "Basic " + username:password encoded in base64.

Turns out, the content of the Authorization header from the request the drone instance issues is malformed. Decoded it looks like this:

`Authorization: Basic USERNAME:[object Object]`

instead of

`Authorization: Basic USERNAME:password`

I am going to try getting around the

```
password:
  from_secret: repo_password
```

and hope the settings.xml file is the generated properly

Comment: I would start with testing whether the *settings.xml* file is ok by trying to deploy a simple maven "hello world" project and then moving on. Also you can try setting the credentials yourself, it's not that complicated (instead of relying on 3rd party).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for multiple hours (and failing) trying to get this plugin to work I now decided to use a custom step to create the settings.xml using environment variables.
Just set the secret "repo_username" to the username and the secret "repo_password" to the password and you should be good to go.

```yaml
  - name: create settings.xml
    image: alpine:latest
    environment:
      REPO_ID: sytm-nexus
      REPO_USERNAME:
        from_secret: repo_username
      REPO_PASSWORD:
        from_secret: repo_password
    commands:
      - echo '<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"><servers><server><id>'$REPO_ID'</id><username>'$REPO_USERNAME'</username><password>'$REPO_PASSWORD'</password></server></servers></settings>' > settings.xml
```

Edit: As that solution was too hacky for me I created my own drone plugin, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Sytm/drone-mvn-settings)